# How to compile a maven project for different version of jdk with profiles?

Tags: maven, java, profiles

How compile a maven project using different jdk with profiles?
I would like specify different profiles in my POM file, and run command mvn with profile name.
Help me, I'm novice. A complete example would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toolchains - see the [Guide to Using Toolchains](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)

Basically this is what you do:

- prepare your JDKs in `${user.home}/.m2/toolchains.xml` file
- in the pom.xml, for each desired JDK, create a profile which invokes `maven-toolchain-plugin` from phase `validate` (goal `toolchain`)

That's it.

Note that toolchains work only with certain "toolchains-aware" plugins.

*(unfortunately I have no complete example right now)*